# Matplotlib Labels Change Shades Of Grey

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried running the exact same code on two different architectures (one Windows, one Linux).
Same version of Matplotlib. The axes labels are written with different shades of grey (color is default black), as shown in the image. On the same machine, pixels are consistent between runs. The differnt behavior between machines causes bad scores in image comparison tests.

Does anyone know why this could happen, or if there is a way to enforce a certain behavior? I'd be happy also with just a binary color for labels, black/white.

[image]

Comment: It might be worth making sure that both machines use the same backend, although I doubt that the implementations for Linux and Win and Mac are 100% transferable. However - is this not the optimal machine learning dataset?

Comment: Backend is the same (agg). Unfortunately can't do much with these images, if not using basic comparison tools (matplotlib built-ins)

Comment: What about standard rcParams like figure size and dpi that may influence the pixel details? Are they comparable? And does this problem only influence fonts? The fonts or their interpretation might differ between systems.

Comment: Figure size is the same, dpi should be but I didn't verify. It looks like it's only affecting fonts, as plots look exactly the same, the only difference is in labels. The possible font difference is a really good point

Answer (score 0):

You can "force" whatever colour you like into the labels or anything actually. Assuming you have a figure, you can change:

- spines. (Spines are the lines connecting the axis tick marks and noting the boundaries of the data area aka the borders of the plot)

```
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('#dddddd')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('#dddddd') 
ax.spines['right'].set_color('red')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('red')
```

- ticks (Ticks are the values used to show specific points on the coordinate axis aka the thing you're interested in, I think)

```
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red')
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='red')
```

- label

```
    ax.yaxis.label.set_color('red')
    ax.xaxis.label.set_color('red')
```

Comment: The problem with it is that I can force a color like that, but it won't be that plain color for all pixels. If you set 'red', you will see different shades of red in pixels. The distribution of these shades of color is what causes the problem

Comment: If you can see the pixels in the image, it may be a resolution problem. Have you tried to export it as a high resolution plot?   

`plt.savefig('filename.png')`

Saving it as .pdf and cropping the image in Adobe is also good.

Comment: I can see the pixels cause I'm zooming in. I noticed it because automatic image comparison would show those areas as different, when they are not supposed to be.At naked eye they look the same, but they are not when you compare them pixel by pixel